# How do i make lists in a list, in a .js file and then choose a randomd list item using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

(Coding in a .js file, not in the body of a .html)

So, if have a list: `category = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`

and every list item have themselft diffrent choices:

```
category[0] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];
category[1] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];
category[2] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];
```

First: How do i write a list in a list in my .js file? (Guessing you are not able to do like you would in a body with `<ul>` and `<li>` and so on)

Second: How do i randomly generate, a,b or c, and then a random list item within that list?

When i have my generated choice, i would very much like to print it out on the screen.

/W

Comment: want to show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list within a list just by using a multi-dimensional array as you did above.  However, if you want a mapping like a -> [list], you need to use an object:

```
{"a": ['long textstring1'], "b": ['long textstring1']}
```

It is actually easier if you are using an array instead of an object to get the random property.  For example:

```
var category = [['ls1', 'ls2'], ['ls1', 'ls2']];
```

Then you could get a random sub-list using:

```
var rand = category[Math.floor(Math.random() * (category.length + 1)) + min];
```

[There are several answers on how to get a random property from a JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20random%20property)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you for the first part of your question, generating the lists based on your input:

```
var category = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
category[0] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];
category[1] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];
category[2] = ['long textstring1', 'longtextstring2', 'longtextstring3'];

var container = document.getElementById("container");
for(var i = 0; i < category.length; i++)
{
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    for(var j = 0; j < category[i].length; j++)
    {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        var txt = document.createTextNode(category[i][j]);
        listItem.appendChild(txt);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    container.appendChild(list);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T88bg/).

Comment: Just noticed you could also use jQuery. If that's the case, you can easily use `$("<ul />")` to create new DOM elements, and  use the jQuery methods to append etc.